# How can I print to a string in LLVM

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I want to print an instruction in LLVM to a string instead of the screen. I use `I->print( errs() )` to print to the screen. How can I instead put the instruction in a string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this,

```
std::string str;
llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(str);
I->print(rso);
```