# LLVM - How to Construct llvm::Value from a std::string

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

```
std::string myIR = "%3 = alloca i32, align 4";
```

How would I convert a C++ `std::string` (such as the one above) to a `llvm::Value`? I can put an `llvm::Instruction` into a `std:string` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515844/how-can-i-print-to-a-string-in-llvm) SO answer shows, but I am unsure on how to go from a `std::string` to an `llvm::Instruction` or a `llvm::Value`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish (seems a bit dubious), since the typical usage for printing or converting to string is for debug purposes (the [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515844/how-can-i-print-to-a-string-in-llvm) that you linked).

Having said that, maybe you can have a look at the `llvm::parseAssemblyString()` function of the [`Parser.h`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/Parser_8h.html) header file (also note that there is a `llvm::parseAssemblyString()` function too among other variants). This requires wrapping your IR at least into a function (you can create a dummy `void foo(void)` one or something similar).

A minimal (incomplete) example would be (at least LLVM 3.9.0):

```
#include <memory>
// using std::unique_ptr

#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
// using llvm::LLVMContext

#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
// using llvm::Module

#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
// using llvm::verifyModule

#include "llvm/AsmParser/Parser.h"
// using llvm::parseAssemblyString

#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h"
// using llvm::SMDiagnostic

#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
// using llvm::raw_string_ostream

#include "llvm/Support/ErrorHandling.h"
// using llvm::report_fatal_error

std::string myAsmIR = "...";
llvm::LLVMContext theContext;
llvm::SMDiagnostic theDiagnostic;

std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> myModule = llvm::parseAssemblyFile(myAsmIR, theDiagnostic, theContext);

// for verifying and printing diagnostics from the parsed file/string
std::string msg;
llvm::raw_string_ostream os(msg);
theDiagnostic.print("", os);

if(llvm::verifyModule(*myModule, &(llvm::errs()))
   llvm::report_fatal_error(os.str().c_str());
```

This will get you a `llvm::Module` that you can process the usual way (e.g. `*myModule->begin()` for getting the first function).

Lastly, you have tagged your question as "llvm-3.0", but that's quite an old version, so not sure how much this API is there, but you can dig around.

Let us know if you find another way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited the question to be more clear and removed the llvm-3.0 tag. I'm trying to get llvm::Instructions and llvm::Values as std::strings so I can easily sort and compare them in a std::set<>. I can't figure out how to compare two std::set<Instruction> for equality.

Comment: @ChrisSmyth well, you can't compare instructions like that because each instruction is a different pointer. So, you need to compare the contents where those pointers point to. Again, comparing strings is not very safe in this case, because an instruction may have the same opcode and operands, but might have different attributes, so your textual comparison will fail. I think you need to define what equal instructions mean first (still not sure what's the end goal here).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IRBuilder<>.CreateGlobalStringPtr** or **IRBuilder<>.CreateGlobalString** functions to create a global string from stl string:

```
LLVMContext context;
IRBuilder<> builder(context);

std::string str = "hello world"
Value * v = builder.CreateGlobalString(StringRef(str),"varName");
...
```