# Instruction ID or number in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-3.0

In Execution.cpp, I can get all instructions and the values of all variables. Is there any method to get the ID or the number of each instruction.

Comment: Could you elaborate what do you mean by instruction ID? Or better what do you want to achieve? Maybe there is another way of doing this.

Comment: In Execution.cpp in interpreter, I need to get values of each variable, in each instruction, I can do this. But, I need to insert this value to a map of instruction number and address of this value and the value, to do some analysis. I may use instruction as a string instead of number, but how could I retrieve this string in ExecutionEngine.cpp functions or Execution.cpp functions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's anything in LLVM that acts like an instruction ID, but the value of the instruction pointer (`Instruction*`) seems to serve your purpose. LLVM does not move instructions around, so you'll be safe as long as you don't move them yourself.

Meanwhile, if you prefer the string representation of instructions that's also doable, by

```
Instruction *I /* = what_ever_you_have */;
std::string str;
llvm::raw_string_ostream rso(str);
I->print(rso);
```

but note that a string does not suffice as a unique identifier of an instruction.

(Code is taken from [How can I print to a string in LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515844/how-can-i-print-to-a-string-in-llvm).)